# Conditions for the function to produce Positive Values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following function

```
2* Pi *r^2*(3*a + 8*b^3 + 6*b*r^2)
```

r is the radius of a small circle, hence the value of r is extremely small, where a,b are the coordinates in an x-y axis, hence a,b can be either positive or negative values .
To find whether the above function produces output > 0 , the condition 3 a + 8 b^3 > 0  must be met, since r^2 will be positive, albeit a small positive value. Hence for the above function to be greater than 0, 3 a + 8 b^3 > 0 must be met.

Now take the example of the below function

```
 (Pi *r^2*(8*a + 3*(4*b^2 + r^2)))/4
```

For the above function to be positive what are the conditions for a & b.
The above function when expanded yields:

```
(Pi *r^2*(8*a + 12*b^2 + 3r^2)))/4
```

12*b^2 will always be positive, hence for the above function to produce values greater than 0, shouldn't the condition required only be 8a > 0? Or am i missing something here?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your discussion of the first expression is incomplete.

- When $a = 25/6$, $b = -1$, and $r = 1$, we compute $3a + 8b^3 = 9/2 > 0$ and $3a + 8b^3 + 6 b r^2 = -3/2 < 0$, so the original expression can be negative when the condition you write is met.
- When $a = -19/6$, $b = 1$, and $r = 1$, we compute $3a + 8b^3 = -3/2 < 0$ and $3a + 8b^3 + 6 b r^2 = 9/2 > 0$, so the original expression can be positive when the condition you write fails.

Here is a correct method to understand the positivity of the first expression...
$$ 2 \pi r^2 (3a + 8b^3 + 6 b r^2)  $$
is the product of a positive constant, $2\pi$, a nonnegative constant, $r^2$, and the expression $3a + 8b^3 + 6 b r^2$.  We are told that $r$ is the radius of a circle, not a point, so $r > 0$ and the expression $r^2$ is positive.  The expression is linear in $a$, so is positive when $a > \frac{-8b^3 - 6 br^2}{3}$.

Then you study
$$  \frac{\pi r^2 (8a + 3(4b^2 + r^2))}{4}  \text{.}  $$
The denominator is positive, so this is positive when its numerator is.  The numerator is the product of a positive constant, $\pi$, a nonnegative number, $r^2$, and the expression $8a + 3(4b^2 + r^2)$.  Again, since $r$ is the radius of a circle, $r > 0$, so $r^2$ is positive.  Again, this is linear in $a$, so we obtain $a > \frac{-12b^2 - 3r^2}{8}$.  Alternatively, this is quadratic in $b$, so we can write an equivalent expression (using the quadratic formula to partition the $ab$-plane and testing on which side(s) the inequality is satisfied):
$$  a > \frac{-3r^2}{8} \text{ or } \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{-8a}{3} - r^2} < b  \text{ or } b < \frac{-1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{-8a}{3} - r^2}  \text{.}  $$
(For an example where this $a$ condition is not met and the $b$ condition is, consider $a = -9/8$, $b = -1$, and $r = 1$.)